# Can you mount UFS partitions made in Solaris (Sparc) on Solaris (x86)?

Tags: mount, solaris, storage

I am reading about Endianness and it seems both systems save their data differently.

Sparc uses big endian and x86 uses small endian, meaning the byte order is different.

That makes me wonder... is it possible to mount UFS partitions from Sparc on x86-systems?

Comment: As it is over the network I think the code is compatible and it will be able to mount that.

Comment: @Atique: I think "UFS shares" is misleading, I understand the question to be about physical partitions so no networking (outside perhaps SAN) is involved.

Comment: I have corrected the typo. I am not talking about NFS shares

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no support for big endian UFS on Solaris running on x86.
Here is a [discussion](http://www.archivum.info/ufs-discuss@opensolaris.org/2007-04/00005/Re-%28ufs-discuss%29-Big-and-little-endian.html) explaining why it wasn't implemented.

As stated in the link, another option would be to use Linux which UFS implementation supports both little end big endian UFS mounts.